# JavaFX 2.0 TableViewBuilder, how to use

Tags: java, javafx-2

Given a Person class:

```
public class Person {
    private StringProperty firstName;
     private StringProperty lastName;

     public Person(String firstName, String lastName){
         setFirstName(firstName);
         setLastName(lastName);
     }

     //SETTERS
     public final void setFirstName(String value) { firstNameProperty().set(value); }
     public final void setLastName(String value) { lastNameProperty().set(value); }

     //GETTERS
     public String getFirstName() { return firstNameProperty().get(); }
     public String getLastName() { return lastNameProperty().get(); }

     //PROPERTY GETTERS
     public StringProperty firstNameProperty() { 
         if (firstName == null) firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "firstName");
         return firstName; 
     }     
     public StringProperty lastNameProperty() { 
         if (lastName == null) lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "lastName");
         return lastName; 
     } 
}
```

I recreated the JavaFX API example on TableView:

```
public class TestTableViewBuilder extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
       primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");

       final ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Person("Jacob", "Smith"),
            new Person("Isabella", "Johnson"),
            new Person("Ethan", "Williams"),
            new Person("Emma", "Jones"),
            new Person("Michael", "Brown")
        );

       TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();

       table.setItems(data);

       TableColumn<Person,String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<Person,String>("First Name");
       firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("firstName"));
       TableColumn<Person,String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<Person,String>("Last Name");
       lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("lastName"));

       table.getColumns().setAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol);       

       Group root = new Group();
       root.getChildren().add(table);
       primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
       primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I've been trying without success to use the TableViewBuilder to recreate the same table. Anyone have an idea how to use JavaFX 2.0 TableViewBuilder to create a TableView with an existing ObservableList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewBuilderExample extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
  @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    final ObservableList<?> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
      new Person("Jacob", "Smith"),
      new Person("Isabella", "Johnson")
    );

    stage.setScene(
      new Scene(
        TableViewBuilder.create().items((ObservableList<Object>) data).columns(
          TableColumnBuilder.create().text("First Name").cellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("firstName")).build(),
          TableColumnBuilder.create().text("Last Name").cellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("lastName")).build()
        ).build()
      )
    );
    stage.show();
  }
}
```

There are some strange things going on with the generic type usage in the Builders.  I would have liked instead to say something like `TableViewBuilder<Person>.create()`, but `TableViewBuilder` has a recursive type as a second generic type parameter which must be supplied to it, so I could not get that strategy to work.  The code above is next best thing I could come up with, but it still have some strange typing going on with the `ObservableList<?>` definition of the data and the need to cast the data to an `ObservableList<Object>` in the Builder.

Based on Sergey's insight for a type parameterization syntax for the builders I was able to create the following builder which will work with a data type of `ObservableList<Person>`

```
TableViewBuilder.<Person>create().items(data).columns(
  TableColumnBuilder.<Person, String>create()
    .text("First Name").cellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("firstName"))
  .build(),
  TableColumnBuilder.<Person, String>create()
    .text("Last Name").cellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("lastName"))
  .build()
).build()
```

After this exercise, I would be even more inclined to checkout the [DataFX](http://www.javafxdata.org/) project if I had to do this kind of stuff a lot . . .

Comment: Thanks, the 2nd piece of code is the solution. I would never had figured it out from the API.

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is in the fact that `Builders` are created by factories named `create`, so you have to parametrize them, not the `Builder` class name itself which only plays namespace role here.

This way:

```
TableViewBuilder.<Person>create().build();
```